# Child component does not re-render parent after POST request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to re-render a list  of comments when I post a new comment.
The state in my parent component is set to **false**, when I post a comment from the child component I want to update that state.
I can console.log the state after the POST request and I can see that it changes from false to true, but its not re-rendering my parent component.
So far the I can see the new comment only when I manually I refresh the page.
I try to change the state with a callback function from the parent but it doesn't work.
I believe it is maybe a asynchronous problem but I don't know how to tackle it.

Any ideas what is wrong?

**PARENT**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PostCommentForArticle from './PostCommentForArticle'
import axios from 'axios';
import './Comments.css'

class CommentsForArticle extends Component {
  state = {
    isPosted: false
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.comments.map(comment => {
          return (
            <div class="container" id="container-comments">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                  {comment.created_by}
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                  {comment.created_at}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row-combody">{comment.body}</div>
              <div class="row-belongsto">{comment.belongs_to}</div>
              <div class="row-votes">{comment.votes}
                <i class="far fa-thumbs-up" id="icon" onClick={() => {
                  this.incrementCommentVote(comment._id)
                  this.setState({ currCommentVote: comment.votes++ })
                }}></i>
                <i class="far fa-thumbs-down" id="icon" onClick={() => {
                  this.decrementCommentVote(comment._id)
                  this.setState({ currCommentVote: comment.votes-- })
                }}></i>
                <i class="far fa-times-circle" id="icon" onClick={() => {
                  this.deleteComment(comment._id)
                  this.setState({ isCommentDeleted: true })
                }}></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
        <PostCommentForArticle
          article={this.props.article}
          func={this.checkIfPosted} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  incrementCommentVote = (id) => {
    axios
      .put(
        `https://ncnewsapp.herokuapp.com/api/comments/${id}?vote=up`,
        "mytoken",
        { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" } }
      )
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
    //insert error page component
  }
  decrementCommentVote = (id) => {
    axios
      .put(
        `https://ncnewsapp.herokuapp.com/api/comments/${id}?vote=up`,
        "mytoken",
        { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" } }
      )
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
    //insert error page component
  }
  deleteComment = (data) => {
    axios
      .delete(
        `https://ncnewsapp.herokuapp.com/api/comments/${data}`,
        "mytoken",
        { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" } }
      )
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }

  checkIfPosted = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({ isPosted: data })
  }

}
export default CommentsForArticle;
```

**CHILD**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Articles from './Article';
import axios from 'axios';
import './PostCommentForArticle.css';

class PostCommentForArticle extends Component {
  state = {
    userName: '',
    input: '',
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form id="post-comment-form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter username" value={this.state.userName} onChange={this.getUserName} />
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Post a comment.</small>
          </div>

          <div class="input-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea" value={this.state.input} onChange={this.getUserInput}></textarea>
            <br />
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.postComment()}>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  getUserName = (event) => {
    this.setState({ userName: event.target.value });
  }
  getUserInput = (event) => {
    this.setState({ input: event.target.value });
  }
  postComment = () => {
    let id = this.props.article[0]._id;
    const { userName } = this.state;
    const { input } = this.state
    axios.post(`https://ncnewsapp.herokuapp.com/api/articles/${id}/comments?user=${userName}`,
      {
        "comment": `${input}`,

      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.props.func(true)
      })
  }

}
export default PostCommentForArticle;
```

Comment: maybe you need a `bind` in `func={this.checkIfPosted.bind(this)}` ?

Comment: where did you update the new comment in parent component?

Comment: @Dario it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @riwu at the bottom of the parent I have a function that will receive true from the post request and I want to set the state with true and re-render the parent

Comment: why would re-rendering the parent show the new comment if the only state change is a boolean that you don't use? Do you have any lifecycle method in your parent?

Comment: @riwu hmm, I think when I change the state with the boolean I pass from the child will re-render the parent? Obviously I am wrong and no I don't have a lifecycle method in the parent, but I guess I need one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just updating the flag `isPosted` in `CommentsForArticle`, but the comments are generated from the `this.props.comments`. You must make sure that the new comment is added to the `comments` list, of course from where ever it is getting passed or you may consider adding the comments to `CommentsForArticle`'s state and add the new comment instead of just updating the flag.

When you are refreshing the page, you are getting those new comments and hence it shows all of them.